# How to make a "Hello world" kernel

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, virtualbox, osdev, grub

I followed [this article](https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones) on how to make a very simple kernel which prints "Hello, World". The files to my project are available on [Github](https://github.com/MOME05/Assembly).

I built my cross compiler from this [project](https://github.com/rm-hull/barebones-toolchain). I use these command to cross compile, assemble, and build my ISO (CD-ROM image):

```
i686-elf-as boot.s -o boot.o
i686-elf-gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra
i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc
mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub
cp myos.bin isodir/boot/myos.bin
cp grub.cfg isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o myos.iso isodir
```

When I tried to execute it on VirtualBox, it gives the following message:

> FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.

Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

P.S. I use Ubuntu subsystem for Windows 10

Comment: Did you set up grub? Does it start at least?

Comment: @Michael Petch I use barebones-toolchain

Comment: The files are exactly as the guide. For the compling commands: `i686-elf-as boot.s -o boot.o` `i686-elf-gcc -c kernel.c -o kernel.o -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -O2 -Wall -Wextra` `i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o myos.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o kernel.o -lgcc` `mkdir -p isodir/boot/grub
cp myos.bin isodir/boot/myos.bin
cp grub.cfg isodir/boot/grub/grub.cfg
grub-mkrescue -o myos.iso isodir`

Comment: The code: https://github.com/MOME05/Assembly/upload

Comment: On my Win10 system I installed Xming X11 server from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming . Under Ubuntu 18.04 WSL I did a `sudo apt-get install grub2-common grub-pc xorriso qemu-system-i386` . I git cloned your project, did the commands you gave above and it produced a file `myos.iso`. I made sure I did an `export DISPLAY=:0` . I then ran `qemu-system-i386 -cdrom myos.iso` and it worked as it displayed `Hello, kernel World!`

Comment: @Michael Petch I tried to do `qemu-system-i386 -cdrom myos.iso`, but it returned me `Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting`. Where am I supposed to put `export DISPLAY=:0`?

Comment: @Michael Petch I tried now to boot in VirtualBox after doing `sudo apt-get install grub2-common grub-pc xorriso qemu-system-i386` and recompiling everything and works!!!!! Thank you! (Anyways what does `Could not initialize SDL(No available video device) - exiting` mean?

Comment: @SimoneBroili When running programs that need graphics under Linux `Could not initialize SDL(No available video device)` usually means SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer)couldn't find an X server to communicate with. X servers are graphics servers that programs communicate with to display things. They don't need to be on the same computer the program is running. In my comment I said I  installed Xming. Xming is such a server that runs naively on Windows. If you run Xming and do `export DISPLAY=:0` it should be enough got graphics programs like QEMU to output to.

Comment: The `export DISPLAY=:0` is issued in your Ubuntu terminal before running qemu-system-i386 (or any X11 programs). You also have to make sure that XMing is running on Windows. You can also place `export DISPLAY=:0` at the end of your `~/.bashrc`  file so it is automatically done every time your Windows Ubuntu terminal is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely there is a GRUB component missing or an incorrect version of Xorriso. In the Bare Bones article you linked to it says this:

> You can easily create a bootable CD-ROM image containing the GRUB bootloader and your kernel using the program grub-mkrescue. **You may need to install the GRUB utility programs and the program xorriso** (version 0.5.6 or higher).

When using `grub-mkrescue` to make ISO images, more often than not unbootable ISOs is a result of Xorisso installation missing. If `grub-mkrescue` runs but doesn't produce ISOs at all then likely a GRUB component is missing. To ensure that you have all the GRUB and Xorriso components installed install the components on modern Ubuntu releases with:

```
sudo apt-get install grub2-common grub-pc xorriso
```

Then attempt to rebuild and rerun your ISO image in VirtualBox.

Comment: How can I get the GRUB tools and xorriso for mac? I tried brew installing, but it didn't find them.

Comment: @KlausMaria : I don't use MacOS to do OSDev so I'm unsure. This particular answer covers `ubuntu` since it was tagged as such.